# Update foreign key value through view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

So I have two tables (`ExampleEnum` and `Data`) joined into a view View.

When I do `UPDATE View SET exampleEnum="NEW_VALUE" ...`, MySQL thinks that I want to update the original row of `ExampleEnum` to `NEW_VALUE` but I just want to update the foreign key reference in `Data` to the value that will be joined to `NEW_VALUE` in `ExampleEnum`.

**ExampleEnum**

```
id  name

1   Fruit
2   Vegetable
```

**Data**

```
id  exampleEnum
1   1
2   1
```

**View**

```
id  exampleEnum

1   Fruit
2   Fruit
```

I want to run `UPDATE View SET exampleEnum = 'Vegetable' WHERE id = 1` and have the `exampleEnum` value on row 1 in `Data` be set to `2`:

**Data** (after update)

```
id  exampleEnum
1   1
2   2
```

Comment: if you want to change the logic in the view you have to modify the view , update command will update the values in origin tables

Comment: You will need to give us more detail in order for us to help you.  Specifically, show us the actual SQL code of your View and UPDATE command, as well as the Data table definition.  It's OK to remove any irrelevant columns, or even change the names for security reasons, just make sure that it can still replicate the problem.

Comment: You cannot update the table on the side "many" via view. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: Updated with examples

Comment: `enum` is a very bad name for a column in MySQL because it is also the name of a type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah noted, bear in mind that this is just an example

Comment: And just to observe, views offer no useful purpose in MySQL

Comment: We still need to see the View's code.  The view's data output is not enough because the problem is almost certainly in the view's code and/or relational logic.